How do I calculate a new column in power bi that sums the values of a column from Table1 then subtracts the sum of groups of rows in Table 2?
I'm new to Power BI and struggling with writing DAX to define a new column for what seems like it should be a  simple subtraction exercise.  Here's a simulation of my data tables:



Resource
Cpty Type 1
Cpty Type 2
Cpty Type 3
Cpty Type 4




Bulldozer
10
50
0
0


Dump Truck
150
150
150
150


Backhoe
25
0
50
50






Project
Work Type
Resource
Usage Hours




Apple
Type 1
Bulldozer
8


Apple
Type 2
Dump Truck
100


Peach
Type 3
Dump Truck
50


Pear
Type 4
Backhoe
42


Pear
Type 1
Compactor
98


Pear
Type 3
Excavator
80


Plum
Type 2
Dump Truck
50


Plum
Type 1
Dump Truck
25


Pineapple
Type 4
Dump Truck
75



I provide a dashboard for each resource by slicing/filtering on the resource.  Table 1 has a single row for each resource with multiple capacity type columns that need to be added together to get the [Capacity] for the resource.
Table 2 has the detailed consumption data that shows a project, type of work, the resource and the hours consumed.  I want subtotals of usage hours for each group of [resource and work type usage] to show in cards on the dashboard, then I need to show the over/under utilization by taking the summed [Capacity] for the resource from Table 1 and subtracting the sum of each of the [resource and work type usage]for that resource from Table 2.
Using the data example, on a report for the Dump Truck:

the Capacity card should show 600 hours
the Work Type 1 card should show 25 hours
the Work Type 2 card should show 150 hours
the Work Type 3 card should show 50 hours
the Work Type 4 card should show 75 hours
the Utilization card should show under-utilization of 300 hours.

I've fiddled with CALCULATE statements and SUM and SUMX but can't get it right.
I was expecting to be able to take a SUM from Table 1 and subtract a SUMX from Table 2, with a slicer/filter applied at the page level. I've tried putting this new column in both Table1 and Table 2, which are joined on [Resource].  The DAX builder doesn't let me choose data from the other table when attempting the calculation.
Help greatly appreciated!

could you pls explain how to get 600? why type 1 is 25 hours? pls elaborate the calculation logic.

Filtering just on the Dump Truck, total available capacity = [Cpty Type 1] of 150 + [Cpty Type 2] of 150 + [Cpty Type 3] of 150 + [Cpty Type   4] of 150 for a sum of 600.
Another view of the report will be filtered on the Backhoe, where  available total capacity = 25+0+50+50. Another view of the report will be filtered on the Bulldozer, where available total capacity = 10+50+0+0.
Needless to say I'm replacing real values with make-believe for this posting.

in the first table, select the first column and unpivot other column in PQ



create a dim table

dim_table = DISTINCT('Table'[Resource])

create realtionships among three tables


then you can use filter to switch the output from different resources



